# Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImageView' to parameter of type 'UIImage*'

Tags: ios, uiimageview

i am making an app in which i am using a check box button inside my uitableview cell.i have two images tick.png and uncheck.png. when i click on the button which have uncheck.png as its background image, the image will set to tick.png. all are working fine but i want to set frame of that tick image how it will done? i have tried following code but receiving a warning which is mentioned above
Below is my sample code snippet

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }
 [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];






    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
        UIImageView *activityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                          initWithImage:statusImage];
        activityImageView.frame=CGRectMake(100, 50, 78, 80);

          [cell.button setImage:activityImageView
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }

    cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    return cell;
}
```

and i am recieving warning on it:

```
[cell.button setImage:activityImageView
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

output showing 
[image: output showing]

[image: i want this]

i want this
any idea?

Comment: `[cell.button setImage:statusImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
The error is quite explicit, the parameter waited after `setImage` is an `UIImage` object and not an `UIImageView` object. Then set the frame of `cell.button`

Comment: `[cell.button setImage:activityImageView.image
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting imageview on button . Instead of it you need to set image .

```
[cell.button setImage:activityImageView.image
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```